# How to scrape a website using selected words if present?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have used Beautifulsoup to scrape a website. My current code helps me to get the website content in HTML format. I used soup to find the word if it is present or not but I am not able to get the paragraph it belongs to.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make a request
page = requests.get(
    "https://manychat.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Extract title of page
page_title = soup.title.text

# Extract body of page
page_body = soup.body

# Extract head of page
page_head = soup.head

# print the result
print(page_body, page_head)

thirdParty = soup.find(text = 'Facebook')
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the areas you're interested in searching are of a common kind, like  <div> with a common class.  So, you have Soup return all of the <div>s with that class, and you search the div text for your word.